# Talent Agency Scam?

Tags: scams

I have been working with a Talent Agency in Florida and have spent about $2,000+ for a Showcase, Couple Classes (which i have attended online) and etc. I've already booked my ticket to go to the Showcase but now I'm a bit skeptical. I reached out to the agency owner requesting fewer classes due to a busy schedule and financial problems but the agent responded passive aggressively.

I cannot find any past information about the person that is running the talent agency nor can I find any advertisement about the Showcase itself.

I tried calling the Hotel that the Showcase will be presented but I would have to wait till tomorrow to call.

Does this seem like a scam?

Comment: Calling the hotel seems like a good idea, if there's an event booked and there were classes provided then it doesn't seem like a scam. Might not be a good value, but that's subjective.

Comment: I think there have been cases like this where fraud agents prey on people like you. I believe there are reports on news channels for such cases. I am assuming they have promised you the moon to entice you to spend the money.   https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0071-look-out-modeling-scams   https://www.scam-detector.com/article/how-to-become-a-model-and-talent-representation-scam

Comment: Yes, this seems like a scam.

Comment: We would probably benefit from some more details, as it is we know you're out $2K and must book a ticket, but it's not clear what value can be attributed to what you already have and what you will receive. Looking up information and checking references is something you do first, not at the last minute. As to requesting fewer classes and being unable to pay for what ***you*** are requesting, should the agent be happy? Not getting what you pay for is as common as not paying for what you get. If they thought you are talented and gave you a discount, now you back out, whom is scammed in the end?

Comment: So, what happened on the call?